# Ubuntu Studio 16.04.2 focusrite 2i4 on jack

Tags: jack

I recently purchased a Scarlett focusrite 2i4 second generation, works very well out of the box with pulseaudio, however I cannot use it in jack, if I go into jackctl, the audio tab displays only two outputs (playback_1, playback_2) which use my laptop speakers (Dell xps 9550) So I can't use the interface with SuperCollider, or Ardour for example. Could someone please refer me to how I could set this up?

Thank you very much in advance,

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I was kindly helped in the following forum:

http://new-supercollider-mailing-lists-forums-use-these.2681727.n2.nabble.com/Scarlett-2i4-Focusrite-UbuntuStudio-16-04-td7633424.html

in qjackctl you should go to Setup/Advanced, in "output device" and "input device" you should see your soundcard. e.g. "USB, 0" Apply changes and restart jack.

cheers!

Jorge.